# What are the Defences to a yellow parking violence notice in Toronto?

Tags: ontario, parking

Three days ago, I got a [yellow parking violation notice](https://www.toronto.ca/services-payments/tickets-fines-penalties/dispute/new-parking-violation-dispute-process/). I don't want to divulge my case's fact pattern to protect privacy. Suffice it to say that I was with my elderly mom in the car, who has many pre-existing health conditions. We genuinely believed she had a medical emergency.

What defences can I invoke? What's the relevant case law or statute? I read the  [Administrative Penalty By-law](http://www.toronto.ca/legdocs/bylaws/2017/law0799.pdf) and it mentions "Undue Hardship", but it doesn't appear to say anything on defences based on medical reasons.

[image]

I know New York law differs from Toronto law, but [Can you beat an NYC parking ticket with a medical emergency?](https://newyorkparkingticket.com/medical-emergency/) feels relevant.

> Absolutely. If you are involved in an unexpected medical emergency affecting a human being, you can raise the medical emergency as a defense to an NYC parking ticket.You will need to submit evidence of the medical emergency, such as:
>
> - “Hospital or Clinic emergency admission paperwork”
> - “Statement from medical staff indicating the nature of the emergency”
>
> Raising a properly documented medical emergency as a defense to an NYC parking ticket doesn’t guaranty a dismissal, but it is a defense that is given serious consideration by the NYC parking ticket hearing officials.

Answer (score 1):

**EXTENUATING CIRCUMSTANCES**

From your [link](https://www.toronto.ca/legdocs/bylaws/2017/law0799.pdf)

> EXTENUATING CIRCUMSTANCES - a special or specified circumstance, including
> such types of extenuating circumstances established by the City Solicitor, that partially or
> fully exempts a person from performance of a legal obligation so as to avoid an
> unreasonable or disproportionate burden or obstacle.